# How to pass state to child component and update the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a parent component called `ProductSearchScreen` which looks like this

```
function ProductSearchScreen() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [search] = useSearchParams();
    const category = search.get('searchItem');
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(//endpoint, {
        params: {
            category : category
        }}).then((response) => {
            setProducts(response.data);
        })
    }, [category])
    // console.log(products)

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <strong>{category}</strong> - {products.length} items
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="filters-text-and-sort-by-row">
                    <Col className="filters-text-container" xs={6} sm={6} md={8} lg={9} xl={9} xxl={9}>
                        <h5>FILTERS</h5>
                    </Col>
                    <SortBy products={products} />
                </Row>
                <hr />
                <Row>
                    <Filters products={products} category={category}/>
                    <Col>
                        {
                            products?.map((product, index) => {
                                return <div key={index}>{product.name} - {product.price} - {product.discount} - {product.created_at}</div>
                            })
                        }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductSearchScreen;
```

And child component `SortBy`

```
function sortFunction(products, sortByValue) {
    const sorted = products.sort((a, b) => {
        switch(sortByValue) {
            case 'new' : return parseISO(b.created_at) - parseISO(a.created_at);
            case 'discount' : return b.discount - a.discount;
            case 'price_desc' : return b.price - a.price;
            case 'price_asc' : return a.price - b.price;
            default : return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        }
    })
    return sorted
}

function SortBy({ products }) {
    const sortByRef = useRef(null);
    const [showSortByMenu, setShowSortByMenu] = useState(false);
    const [selectedSortByValue, setSelectedSortByValue] = useState(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = useSearchParams();
    const [sortedProducts, setSortedProducts] = useState([]);

    const sortByTextPlaceholder = "Sort By: ";

    const sortByOptions = [
        { value : "name", label : "Recommended"},
        { value : "new", label : "What's New"},
        { value : "popularity", label : "Popularity"},
        { value : "discount", label : "Better discount"},
        { value : "price_desc", label : "Price: High to Low"},
        { value : "price_asc", label : "Price: Low to High"},
        { value : "rating", label : "Customer Rating"}
    ]

    const getSortByDisplay = () => {
        if(selectedSortByValue) {
            return selectedSortByValue.label;
        }
        return sortByOptions[0].label
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
            if(sortByRef.current && !sortByRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                setShowSortByMenu(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        };
    })

    const handleSortByMenuOnMouseOver = () => {
        setShowSortByMenu(true);
    }

    const onSortByItemClick = (option) => {
        setSelectedSortByValue(option);
        search.set('sort', option.value);
        setSearch(search, { replace: true });
        getSortByDisplay();
        const sorted = sortFunction(products, option.value) // If i try to create a copy of the products array, it does not do any changes to my rendering
        setSortedProducts(sorted)
    }

    const isSortByItemSelected = (option) => {
        if(!selectedSortByValue) {
            return false;
        }
        return selectedSortByValue.value === option.value;
    }

    return (
        <Col className="sort-by-container" ref={sortByRef}>
            <div className="sort-by-input" onMouseOver={handleSortByMenuOnMouseOver}>
                <div className="sort-by-selected-value">
                    {sortByTextPlaceholder}<strong>{ getSortByDisplay() }</strong>
                </div>
                <div className="sort-by-tools">
                    <div className="sort-by-tool">
                        <SlArrowDown />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {
                showSortByMenu &&
                <div className="sort-by-menu">
                    {
                        sortByOptions.map((option) => {
                            return (
                                <div
                                    key={option.value}
                                    className={`sort-by-items ${isSortByItemSelected(option)} && "selected"`}
                                    onClick={() => { onSortByItemClick(option) }}
                                >
                                    {option.label}
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </Col>
    );
}

export default SortBy;
```

- Is this the right way to pass state from parent to the child and update the state in the child component
- Also what is the best way to sort and filter the `products` array and render here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulty is maintaining a separate `products` state within the `SortBy` component. It is better to maintain only one `products` state which you already have in `ProductSearchScreen`. Have a function in `ProductSearchScreen` which handles sorting, and pass this function down to `SortBy`. Whenever the user changes the sort, call this function.

### Sorting

For example in `ProductSearchScreen`:

```
const handleSort = (optionValue) => {
    // sort products by optionValue and update state with setProducts() in the new order
}

<SortBy handleSort={handleSort} />
// ^ this does not need products as a prop
```

In `SortBy`:

```
function SortBy({ handleSort }) {
    ...
    ...
    const onSortByItemClick = (option) => {
        ...
        handleSort(option.value)
    }
}
```

This way, `ProductSearchScreen` handles the sorting using a single products array in state. `SortBy` is responsible for the UI and to call the `handleSort()` function whenever the user wants to change sort order. When this happens, the state will be updated and `ProductSearchScreen` will re-render the `products?.map()`.

### Filtering

The same principle apples for filtering: maintain the one products state and update it accordingly whenever a filter is needed. For example with a `handleFilter()` function. I would add a `show` boolean property to each product in state and then simply update this depending on the filter being applied. e.g. if filtering by colour red then iterate over products and set `show=true` if the colour is red.

When you render products, you can filter out products which should not be shown.

Instead of:

```
products?.map((product, index) => {
```

You could do:

```
products?.filter(product => product.show).map((product, index) => {
```

This way, you continue to maintain a single array of products in state, no matter what sort or filter is applied. As the sort changes, you simply update the state to the new order. As the filter changes, you simple set `show` to `true/false` as desired.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for explaining how parent-child components work in react